# "expected identifier, found (" when trying to bind a tuple variable

Tags: binding, rust

I'm playing with Rust a little bit, and got stuck. I've the following function:

```
fn addOne(h: (i32, i32, i32)){

    let mut (x, y, z) = h;

    (x+1, y+1, z+1)
}
```

This gives me the following error on compile:

```
example.rs:2:10: 2:11 error: expected identifier, found `(`
example.rs:2    let mut (x, y, z) = h;
```

Is there something wrong with the binding? Sorry if it is such a simple question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `mut` qualifier applies per-variable. When you are destructuring a variable, each variable can be mutable or not:

```
fn add_one(h: (i32, i32, i32)) -> (i32, i32, i32) {
    let (mut x, mut y, mut z) = h;
    (x+1, y+1, z+1)
}
```

Of course, you don't need mutability here at all:

```
fn add_one(h: (i32, i32, i32)) -> (i32, i32, i32) {
    let (x, y, z) = h;
    (x+1, y+1, z+1)
}
```

You could also choose to destructure in the function signature:

```
fn add_one((x, y, z): (i32, i32, i32)) -> (i32, i32, i32) {
    (x+1, y+1, z+1)
}
```

Or use the default tuple accessor methods:

```
fn add_one(h: (i32, i32, i32)) -> (i32, i32, i32) {
    (h.0 + 1, h.1 + 1, h.2 + 1)
}
```

If you want to mutate the tuple in place, you are going to need to provide a *mutable reference* to the tuple. Without knowing more about the problem you are trying to solve, I would actively discourage you from choosing this path, at least until you've profiled and determined you need it:

```
fn add_one(h: &mut (i32, i32, i32)) {
    h.0 += 1;
    h.1 += 1;
    h.2 += 1;
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = (1, 2, 3);
    add_one(&mut a);
    println!("{:?}", a)
}
```

There are lots of ways to write code that is meaningful to you!

Comment: Just another question: If I wanted this function not to return anything, could I still be able to change the variable passed as a parameter (declared as mut)?

Comment: Yes. Like the function only purpose is to add 1 to every element of the tuple, which is declared outside add_one